# Orphaned Case Error in Java

Tags: java

Im a beginner in the coding world. I have been learning Java recently when i came across a speedbump.

First of all heres the code :

```
import  java.util.*;
public class Stuff {

    public static void main(String []args); {


        Scanner identity = new Scanner(System.in);

        String id;

        System.out.println("Please Enter Your Name :");
        id = identity.next();

        Switch (id); {

            case "name1":
            //some code here....
            break; 

            case "name2":
            //some code here....
            break;

            case "name3":
             //some code here....
            break;

            case "name4":
            //some code here....
            break;

            default :
            //some code here....
            break;
        }


    }

}
```

The error

```
 Error: Orphaned case
         case: "name1";
```

I cant seem to find why this is happening and have googles to no avail.

Edit : Some people have said that I am ending Switch early with the semi colon. But when i add it, i get a new error along with the previous one:

```
Error: ';' expected
        Switch (id) {
              ^
```

Comment: You have a semicolon after `Switch (id)`. Take it out. Also, `switch` needs to be lower case.

Comment: You've put a semi-colon behind `switch(id)`. This ends the switch statement which you did not intend.

Comment: `have googles to no avail.` really? the first 5 hits describe exactly your problem :D

Comment: Can you see the difference between `case: "name1";` and `case "name1":`?

Comment: also `public static void main(String []args); {` remove this semicolon too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ran into multiple problems here.

**Problem 1 :**

```
 Switch (id); {

 ----------^
```

Look carefully your `;` ends your `switch` there right away.

Apparently all your `case` statements became orphans :)

**Problem 2 :**

Your `Switch` should be `switch`(lower case *s*)

**Problem 3 :**

One more `;` cause you compile time error at the line

```
public static void main(String []args); {


                                 -----^
```

Note: I strongly suggest you to use an IDE, to save lot of time here. It tells you the compiler errors on the fly.

Comment: Also, `switch` needs to begin with a lowercase `s`

Comment: @BackSlash Mentioned it. :)

Comment: Thanks! Haha, im pretty embarassed that i made such dumb mistakes.

Comment: @AryanSrivastava Don't worry, we too came from that level ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax for the switch statement is wrong.

```
switch (id) {
    case "name1":
        //some code here....
        break; 

    case "name2":
        //some code here....
        break;

    case "name3":
        //some code here....
        break;

    case "name4":
        //some code here....
        break;

    default :
        //some code here....
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you try will need a quite current version of Java because you use `String`s with `switch`.

And you have to

```
switch (id)
```

So please remove the `;`

Answer (score 1):

The semicolon after the `Switch (id);`statement effectively terminates the switch case and the cases you define afterwards are orphan(i.e. without any switch case)

Answer (score 1):

You are finishing the switch statement early:

```
Switch (id); {
```

The real syntax is:

```
switch (id) {
  // your cases
}
```